# Issue with continually editing answers by a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

There was 2 questions which I have posted. One question I posted and then a moderator known as *goldPseudo*  has edited my question, and now it will be unclear for others to understand and the other thing is, that I gave an answer with regard of *Does Islam believes in rebirth?* I have add new things, with the intention of improving in a proper manner, but no, why would I do such thing? This is because of goldPseudo, he has edited my answer to it. And that is practically not correct. Is he the boss of SEN? No, he is not. So why is acting like a bossy? Why he does only to me? And why he does not do to others???

Like this, I can’t improve my answers in a proper manners because he doesn’t let me to improve better than ever....

Does anyone has an idea for this issue?

Comment: Read your prior meta posts and the given answers and ask yourself: 1) what have I done to follow the recommendations and advises given in the answers of my posts? 2) Why am I posting answers without having any clue on the topic? 3) Why am I asking questions that are unclear? 4) Why am i answering without even knowing what is asked?  and 5) Why am I ignoring any helpful advice? ... Moderators and the community try to guide you. This page can't improve as long as we have users which don't even care about the site policies and is resistant against any good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see here.

Since you can't be bothered to give specifics, I had to go through your question history and see which of your posts I had edited to even figure out what you're talking about here.

In particular, I only found five of your questions which included edits by myself:

- https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/42887/revisions (now deleted)
- https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/42876/revisions
- https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/43340/revisions (now deleted)
- https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/43353/revisions
- https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/43204/revisions

Of those, four were edited to rollback revisions where you had fundamentally changed an existing question to a completely new question in order to bypass a question ban, unwelcome behaviour which you'd already been warned about. The fifth, I removed a tag.

As for your answer, the reason for my edit was clearly explained in the revision history. In particular:

> Rollback to Revision 1 - Copy-pasting third-party articles is not welcome behaviour here. Neither is fundamentally changing an answer after it's already been accepted.

As for your argument "Why he does only to me? And why he does not do to others???" simply checking my revision history would show that to be blatantly untrue: The vast majority of the edits I have made are to users who are *not* you. In addition, numerous other users on this site have chosen to edit *your* posts.

If you have *particular* concerns about *any* moderation action, be it taken by a diamond moderator or a regular user, feel free to bring those up in meta. Be *specific*, be *detailed*, and be willing to accept that what the community wants may not be what *you* want. And above all, *assume good faith*.

On the other hand, ranting and pointing fingers with vague and unfounded accusations just because things aren't going your way doesn't help anybody.

If you actually *want* to improve your contributions, it behooves you to actually pay attention to what other more experienced users on the site are telling you so you don't keep making the same mistakes over and over again.

Until then, stop wasting my time.

Comment: Me?? You are the one who waste my time, I’m trying to be very helpful in here and you keep deleting answers‍♂️ How could I be very helpful in here if you keep deleting answers? I want to help others but I can’t.....

Comment: I don’t know what else to try to answer....